# Prove using Epsilon-Delta and Intermediate Value Theorm

Tags: limits, continuity

Suppose that $f,g\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ are continuous functions with $f(a)<g(a)$ and $f(b)>g(b)$. Prove that there exists an $x\in(a,b)$ with $f(x)=g(x)$. I believe this uses the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: What can you say about $h\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$, given by $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but that is far too vague. I'm just lost.

Comment: Is $h$ continuous? What can you say about $h(a)$, $h(b)$? What das the IVT imply?

Comment: Yes $h$ is continuous, but how does that help?